# Sampling without using random()?

Tags: algorithm, sampling

I was recently asked to implement a sampleStream() method that would choose each element with equal probability, but not use random(). I thought the interviewer was looking for reservoir sampling, but as I stumbled through it, he added that it was an approach called "[stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling)". Admittedly, I may have been thrown off by that, because there is a statistical method called stratified sampling, and I was trying to think of how I could use that to sample elements from a stream without random. The inputs he specified were the number of items to sample, and a rate at which I should sample (something like 1000/100,000).

Anyway, I'm still stuck on this problem, even though I already didn't get the job for not answering it properly. Googling has failed me here. Can anyone help me understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to implement stratified sampling is to sort the list by the keys used for stratification and then do a 1 in n sampling.

Technically, sorting isn't necessary if the keys are categories.  In this (typical) case, a hashing method can be used.  The idea is still the same:  1 in n sampling on an "ordered" list.

Perhaps this is what the interviewer was referring to.

EDIT:

You can implement stratified sampling on a stream, you would essentially be reading the stream and doing a "bucket" count for each group of similar key values.  When the bucket has some arbitrary value, you would output the record.  When the bucket hits some value (based on the overall frequencies), then you would reset the counter and repeat (or use modulo arithmetic).

However, this doesn't have an equal probability of getting each record.  For that, I really do think you need some sort of randomization.  An approach that comes close would be to store the records for each group in a bucket and then choose a random record when the bucket is full.  You can emulate randomness by using a hash key on some other value (such as the time of insert) and then choosing the the minimum or maximum hash key value.  (And, you can make this more efficient by just storing one record.)

Comment: Thanks for the input! The input was a stream though. I guess you could build up a reservoir, and keep track of the stratification, adding to each strata as you encounter a new element for that strata with some probability. But he didn't want me to use random()-- any thoughts on that?

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I'm not going to mark it as solved yet because  I'm curious what others have to say. 

It is pretty involved for an interview question though. I don't feel quite as clueless for not solving it in the 15 mins provided while being watched!